# How to do GROUP BY on age ranges in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column named "age". I am trying to select a range of ages and then group them by those ranges. Here is what I have got so far, but cant get it to work:

```
select t.age as [range], count(*) as [occurences]
from (
select age,
   case when age >= 0 and age < 10 then '0-9'
   when age >= 10 and age < 20 then '10-19'
   when age >= 20 and age < 20 then '20-29'
   when age >= 30 and age < 40 then '30-39'
   else '40+' end as range
from t) t
group by t.age
```

What would be the simplest way to accomplish what I am trying to do? The column "age" is in table "contact" in my case.

Comment: Well, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I am running this in a query editor in Wavemaker, and it gives me this error:                                                       Run query error: expecting IDENT, found '[' near line 1, column 17 [select t.age as [range], count(*) as [occurences] from ( select age, case when age >= 0 and age < 10 then '0-9' when age >= 10 and age < 20 then '10-19' when age >= 20 and age < 20 then '20-29' when age >= 30 and age < 40 then '30-39' else '40+' end as range from t) t group by t.age ]

Comment: Side comment: Since cases are evaluated sequentially you don't need the lower bound tests at all, i.e. `case when age < 10 the '0-9' when age < 20 then '10-19'... etc`

Comment: Why `[range]` and `[occurrences]` and not just `range` and `occurrences`... why the brackets?

Comment: Thx Jim for that...will modify

Comment: Did you mean `select t.range as range, ...`? Otherwise you don't use the range column in the sub query at all

Comment: I removed the brackets around range and occurences and now get this error: Run query error: unexpected token: ( near line 2, column 6 [select t.age as range, count(*) as occurences from ( select age, case when age >= 0 and age < 10 then '0-9' when age >= 10 and age < 20 then '10-19' when age >= 20 and age < 20 then '20-29' when age >= 30 and age < 40 then '30-39' else '40+' end as range from t) t group by t.age ] Sorry, I am a little over my head with this query.

Comment: Thanks guys. For some reason this query wont run in the wavemaker query editor. I have other queries running fine. It seems I need to find a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine, with a few changes. (Here is [an SQLFiddle to prove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa86a/7).)

```
select t.range, count(*) as `occurences`
from (
select age,
   case when age >= 0 and age < 10 then '0-9'
   when age >= 10 and age < 20 then '10-19'
   when age >= 20 and age < 20 then '20-29'
   when age >= 30 and age < 40 then '30-39'
   else '40+' end as `range`
from t) as t
group by t.range
```

1. MySQL uses [`ident` quoting by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) (and [RANGE is a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) so it needs to be quoted), and;
2. The GROUP BY needs to be over t.range (not t.age) for it to make sense. Likewise, the select clause should select the range.

While I'd recommend choosing a different alias name, it'll parse/execute fine when re-using "t".

Comment: The inline view is unnecessary, it negatively impacts performance. The expression `t.age` in the select list of the outer query should probably be `t.range`, and there is no need for the inline view to return the `age` column.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for pointing out the flaw in the select clause, that was indeed a mistake on my part - silly since I had previously updated the ORDER BY :-/ However, I am saddened to hear that MySQL has problems optimizing such a simple query plan.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to ident quote? Wavemaker query editor calls the escape quotes in the backtick format an unexpected character.

Comment: @user2864740: I wouldn't go as far as saying that MySQL fails; MySQLe way inline views are handled in other RDBMS. MySQL processing  of queries using derived tables is described here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/select-derived.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/select-derived.html).

Comment: @user1218172 You can enable [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes). Otherwise, no: pick a different column name.

Answer (score 1):

This should return the resultset you describe:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.age >= 0  AND t.age < 10 THEN '0-9'
            WHEN t.age >= 10 AND t.age < 20 THEN '10-19'
            WHEN t.age >= 20 AND t.age < 30 THEN '20-29'
            WHEN t.age >= 30 AND t.age < 40 THEN '30-39'
            ELSE '40+'
       END AS `range`
     , COUNT(*) AS `occurrences`
  FROM t
 GROUP BY `range`
```

---

For improved performance, you want to avoid using an inline view.

If you do want to spend the resources to spin through the table and materialize a derived table, then this will also return an equivalent result:

```
SELECT v.range
     , COUNT(*) AS `occurrences`
  FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN t.age >= 0  AND t.age < 10 THEN '0-9'
                     WHEN t.age >= 10 AND t.age < 20 THEN '10-19'
                     WHEN t.age >= 20 AND t.age < 30 THEN '20-29'
                     WHEN t.age >= 30 AND t.age < 40 THEN '30-39'
                     ELSE '40+'
                END AS `range`
               FROM t
       ) v
 GROUP BY v.`range`
```

Comment: Thanks. Am I right that "t" referenced in this query should be replaced by my table name? I dont see any reference to my table otherwise...

Comment: The "`FROM t`" referenced in the queries above match the "`from t`" in your query.